# OpenCV function from outside while loop

Tags: python, opencv

I have a OpenCV program written in python which tracks the position of a ball and uses a webcam as the input. 
How would I now implement a function, that can get the position of the ball only when it's called (i.e. by a keyboard event).
The problem is that the OpenCV algorithm is running in a while loop which would have to be killed before I can call another function.
I'm still kinda new to python and therefore don't know whether or not this is a dumb question.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it's doable! You can get keyboard input from cv2.waitKey(milliseconds).

```py
import cv2

# make it brighter
def brighten(img):
    img[:,:,:] += 10;

# get image
img = cv2.imread("image.jpg");

# loop
done = False;
while not done:
    # do processing stuff

    # show image
    cv2.imshow("Image", img);
    key = cv2.waitKey(1);

    # check for keypresses
    done = key == ord('q'); # when q is pressed
    if key == ord('b'):
        brighten(img);
```